# Утечка памяти в таймере

Tags: windows, winforms, c++-cli

Для меня cli в новинку, но объясните пожалуйста, есть у меня простейший код в таймере:

```
private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    String^ tempString = textBox1->Text;
}
```

Почему происходит утечка 4кб\сек, я не пойму локальный объект String^ нужно освобождать или есть какие - то особенности cli?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это же управляемый код, он будет освобождать память не когда вы этого хотите, а когда GC сработает.

Comment: так и что делать то?

Comment: @Duracell а подождите подольше - придет GC и все уберет. 
Ничего не надо делать - за вас, в данном случае, думает CLI.
Не нравится ее забота - выбросьте и пишите на нормальном C++.